# How to do str vs. int recursion, one character at a time?

Tags: java, recursion, comparison

So I'm stuck on this problem, where you have a method `equalNumbers(String str, int num)`, that determines whether characters in str represent the same number as num. The empty string is equivalent to zero.

```
equalNumbers("123", 123) true
equalNumbers("9", 999) false
```

And so on.

This method is supposed to be **recursive**, so no loops, and no using stuff like `Integer.parseInt`, `Integer.valueOf`, and `integer.decode()`. Helper functions are allowed.

It encourages the use of `charAt(index)` and `Character.gerNumericValue(ch)`.

===

Based on what it encourages me to do, I suppose it wants me to iterate through the string char by char, convert that char to an integer, and compare it to one digit in the integer at a time. It seems the only conversion I am allowed to do is char to int. So my questions are:

1. Should I build a string out of the chars and then convert that whole string into an integer? (Don't think that's allowed)
2. Is it possible to go index by index in an integer, without converting it into a string?

I would show my own code, but I have a conceptual gap about how these data types work.

Comment: "The conceptual obstacles...", please you are expected to ask a question that is clear and to the point and show us your own attempt at solving this. So instead of this design/discussion approach why don't take your ideas and start writing some code from them to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Your use of `String.valueOf` probably defeats the purpose of this exercise, and is probably not allowed to be used (luckily it’s also not necessary).

Comment: Let me give you a hint: do it without a for loop!

Answer (score 1):

Often a public function calls a private recursive function with an extra parameter.
For your code using `get_int_at_index` the extra recursive function would need `i` to be passed.

In your case this is not needed, but then you need to work with `String` (inspecting a tiny part with `charAt`) and `int`. Now I suspect `String.valueOf(int)` was not intended, but inspecting a tiny part of the number, a digit, by number modulo 10 (`% 10`).

Taking modulo ten would give the rightmost digit first, so:

`int num`

- `int digit = num % 10;   // Tiny part we deal with`
- `num = num / 10;         // Rest`

`String str`

- `char ch = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);   // Tiny part`
- `str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1); // Rest`

So

```
public static boolean equalNumbers(String str, int num) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) { // End recursion.
        return num == 0;
    }
    char ch = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    int digit = num % 10;
    if (Character.getNumericValue(ch) != digit) {
        return false;
    }
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    num = num / 10;
    return equalNumbers(str, num); // Recurse.
}
```

Comment: `equalNumbers("", 0)` should be true (see question: it says "The empty string is equivalent to zero."). However, your 2nd code snippet also returns true for `equalNumbers("", 1)` which is wrong.

Comment: @k314159 you are riight, removed the version where "" is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, but you still left the other problem: `assertFalse(equalNumbers("", 1))` fails.

Comment: @k314159 corrected, uncareful copy error, shame on me. Empty string requires num == 0, Actually I did not intend to give a full coded answer, just help the OP on the way.